# How to print Python unit tests coverage report in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I would like to print coverage report for my unit tests written with Python Standard Library's unittest in the same fashion as I am able to print coverage report for unit test files written with pytest using commands `pytest --cov libraries.foo libraries\tests\test_library_foo.py` and then `coverage report -m` with the output:

```
Name                                    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
libraries\tests\test_library_foo.py     200     10    95%     50-65, 70-85
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                   200     10    95%
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [coverage documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4.4/index.html#quick-start):

```bash
$ coverage run -m unittest libraries.foo libraries\tests\test_library_foo.py
$ coverage report -m
```